# CodeIgniter HTML 5 Input Type Issue

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

I am a beginner in programming especially using CodeIgniter Framework. and I have an issue, may be you guys could help me.

Here is the code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php
        echo form_label('Email', 'email');
        echo form_input('email', '', [
            'type'  => 'email',
            'id'    => 'email', 
            'class' => 'form-control'
        ]);
    ?>
</div>
```

when I inspect in browser it shows like this

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" class="form-control">
```

but when I change the code to this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php
        echo form_label('Email', 'email');
        echo form_input([
            'type'  => 'email',
            'name'  => 'email',
            'id'    => 'email', 
            'class' => 'form-control'
        ]);
    ?>
</div>
```

the inspect element shows

```
<input type="email" name="email" value="" id="email" class="form-control">
```

and I am wondering, why I can't use `<input type="email">` with my first code?
Any explanations would be helpful to me, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look at `form_helper` file below is the function for `form_input`. Here you can see when you did not pass an array data by default it takes `$defaults` array so you are not getting `email` type in your first code. Look into below code of `form_input`. [More Details](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#form_input)

```
if ( ! function_exists('form_input'))
{
    /**
     * Text Input Field
     *
     * @param   mixed
     * @param   string
     * @param   mixed
     * @return  string
     */
    function form_input($data = '', $value = '', $extra = '')
    {
        $defaults = array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => is_array($data) ? '' : $data,
            'value' => $value
        );
        return '<input '._parse_form_attributes($data, $defaults)._attributes_to_string($extra)." />\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks man, so helpful and make me understand how form_input works.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is the behavior of the form_input of CodeIgniter framework.

for the method **form_input(a,b,c)** or **form_input(a,b)** , c is extra parameter object and it is optional.
They **can only** create a text field for you whatever any type specified in the **extraParams**.

However, as you mentioned you can still create **type=email** input by applying the overloadded form_input, which is **form_input(extraParameters)**,

I think these two are not the same implementation in CodeIgniter, and the one which accepting an array is the master function thus it provides more feasility for you.

for example you can create the same output of the first code by using the second one. but you can't do it reversely.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php
        echo form_label('Email', 'email');
        echo form_input([
            'type'  => 'text',
            'name'  => 'email',
            'value'  => '',
            'id'    => 'email', 
            'class' => 'form-control'
        ]);
    ?>
</div>
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st example, by entering all parameters as value, it will default to **text input**, by assuming 1st parameter as **name**, 2nd parameter as **value**, and 3rd parameter as **extra information**.

For the 2nd example, you well defined them in array that produce the result your want.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by editing the form_helper.php under system>helpers, and adding a new function called form_input_email() like this;

```
if ( ! function_exists('form_input_email'))
{
    /**
     * Email Input Field
     *
     * @param   mixed
     * @param   string
     * @param   mixed
     * @return  string
     */
    function form_input_email($data = '', $value = '', $extra = '')
    {
        $defaults = array(
            'type' => 'email',
            'name' => is_array($data) ? '' : $data,
            'value' => $value
        );

        return '<input '._parse_form_attributes($data, $defaults)._attributes_to_string($extra)." />\n";
    }
}
```